# Adding event.stopPropagation(); to all input boxes keyup

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

What jquery function would I use to stop `keyup` in all `<input>` from propagating through to the body.

I've used   `event.stopPropagation();` for clicking a specific element; not sure how to use this for all inputs.

thanks everyone !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input, textarea").keyup(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
```

Added it to the `textarea` too, just to be safe.

Comment: @cereallarceny - I'm a quick typist ;-)

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/FrzDuellImBoisDeBoulogneDurand1874.jpg/300px-FrzDuellImBoisDeBoulogneDurand1874.jpg

Comment: oops...I meant to thank you, @ahren. But accepting your answer should do the trick!